# Is it safe to use [innerHTML] in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I have seen conflicting reports that it is dangerous to use the [innerHTML] tag in Angular2+. Is that still the case or has it since been fixed?

for example is this code dangerous:

```
<div [innerHTML]="post.body"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's safe. Have a look at the [Angular security documentation](https://angular.io/guide/security).

Answer (score 21):

as it said in [here](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example) (in angular site itself), it looks like there are no worries about it because angular, automatically recognize the unsafe values and sanitizes them.

here is what written in there:

> Interpolated content is always escaped—the HTML isn't interpreted and the browser displays angle brackets in the element's text content.
>
> For the HTML to be interpreted, bind it to an HTML property such as innerHTML. But binding a value that an attacker might control into innerHTML normally causes an XSS vulnerability. For example, the code contained in a `<script>` tag is executed:
>
> `export class InnerHtmlBindingComponent {
>     // For example, a user/attacker-controlled value from a URL.
>     htmlSnippet = 'Template <script>alert("0wned")</script> <b>Syntax</b>';
>   }`
>
> Angular recognizes the value as unsafe and automatically sanitizes it, which removes the `<script>` tag but keeps safe content such as the text content of the `<script>` tag and the `<b>` element.

so I think, yes it is safe.

Answer (score 13):

I confirm.

I just tried the following 
`<div [innerHTML]="<span (touch)=() => {alert('Code has been successfully executed on client from external malicious input');}">test xss</span>"></div>`

Nothing is executed and the DOM inspection shows that (touch) has been removed from the span by angular. It's all good ;-)

Comment: even if you would bypass sanitization it would not work.